# Comparison of objects of distinct types

Tags: python, comparison, compare

What's the suggested Python semantics for ordering of objects of distinct types? In other words, what behavior should one implement when a custom-written comparison method (using [rich comparisons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) like e.g. `__lt__`, but perhaps also when using the ‘poor’ comparison `__cmp__` in Python 2) encounters an object of a different type than `self`?

1. Should one invent an order, e.g. “all unexpected objects compare as less than my own type”?
2. Should one throw a `TypeError`?
3. Is there some easy way to let the other object have a try, i.e. if one does `foo < bar` and `foo.__lt__` doesn't know about `bar`'s type, can it fall back to `bar.__gt__`?
4. Are there any guidelines at all about how to achieve sane ordering of objects of distinct types, preferrably a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) but perhaps less?
5. Is there any part in the documentation which explains why `3 < "3"`?

[PEP 207](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) apparently leaves a lot of freedom of how things *can* be implemented, but nevertheless I expect there might be some guidelines how things *should* be implemented to help interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, the “similar questions” list made me aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835019/1468366). It mentions `NotImplemented` as a *return value* (not exception) of rich comparisons. Searching for this keyword in the docs turned up relevant parts as well:

[Python 2 data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> `NotImplemented` – This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name `NotImplemented`. Numeric methods and rich comparison methods may return this value if they do not implement the operation for the operands provided. (The interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or some other fallback, depending on the operator.) Its truth value is true.

And [later on](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> A rich comparison method may return the singleton `NotImplemented` if it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments. By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call [bool()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

[PEP 207](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/):

> If the function cannot compare the particular combination of objects, it should return a new reference to `Py_NotImplemented`.

This answers points 2. and 3. of my original question, at least for the rich comparison scenario. The docs for `__cmp__` don't mention `NotImplemented` at all, which might be the reason why I missed that at first. So this is one more reason to switch to rich comparisons.

I'm still not sure whether returning that value is to be preferred to inventing an order. I guess a lot depends on what ideas the other object might have. And I fear that for a mix of types to achieve any kind of sane orderings, a lot of cooperation might be needed. But perhaps someone else can shed more light on the other parts of my question.